# Why no sqlite exception is thrown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I have a query done in an async method that failed

```
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> futureMaps = await db.query('bete' ,where: 'numBoucle = ? and numMarquage = ? and cheptel = ?',
    whereArgs: [bete.numBoucle, bete.numMarquage, bete.cheptel]);
```

but no exception is thrown as I expected.
Why ?
Should I enclose it in a try-catch to be sure this query has succeded ?

Comment: add the console logs

Comment: @PiyushKumar No logs are written.

Comment: What do you mean by *failed*?

Comment: @forpas When I use step by step, after the query is sent, the step goes directly to the end of method and exits without message and returned value.  Semanticly I know my query is wrong, but I expected an exception or anything which will be written in console.